# Powershell cmdlet: move file to Team Drive

Tags: powershell, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm having a hard time moving a file from a local directory and into Team Drive.

I have a feeling I may be forced to step away from PS and find another route, which I really don't want to but here goes.

This command does not work:

Move-Item -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FieldSmart View\Logs\BgSync.log' -Destination 'G:\Team Drives\LGE Prints\Logs\$env:computername.txt'

This command does work:

Move-Item -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FieldSmart View\Logs\BgSync.log' -Destination C:\Users\ITAdmin\Desktop\Test\$env:computername.txt

The only difference is the destination.

When trying to move a file into Team Drive this is the error that is returned:

> Move-Item : The given path's format is not supported.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - Move-Item -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\FieldSmart View\Logs\BgSync.l ...
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> - CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Move-Item], NotSupportedException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using Single Quotes not Double Quotes when you want a variable replacement in your string.  Your 2nd example has no quotes and the command line will turn that "text" into a string with replacement.

Run this:

```
"single"
'G:\Team Drives\LGE Prints\Logs\$env:computername.txt'

"double"
"G:\Team Drives\LGE Prints\Logs\$env:computername.txt"
```

This link looks good, or any other search for `variable replacement`.

https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-01-13-powershell-variable-substitution-in-strings/

Comment: Thank you, that was actually it!